# Function index does not work in oracle where it is used with other operator

Tags: oracle, indexing, query-performance

You assume this simple query:

```
select name, code 
  from item 
 where length(code) > 5
```

Due to avoiding of full access table, there is an function-index on length(code) by following command:

```
create index index_len_code on item(length(code));
```

The optimizer detects the index and use it(INDEX RANGE SCAN). Nonetheless the optimizer does not detect the above index for the below query:

```
select i.name, i.code
  from item i, item ii
 where length(i.code) - length(ii.code) > 0
```

When I see the execution plan, it is the access full table, not to be index range scan while index is existed on length(code).

Where is wrong and what is wrong?

Comment: How would the index help for your second query?

Comment: Rewrite the condition as `length(i.code) > length(ii.code)`; the optimizer may (or may not) choose to use the index then. You are asking the optimizer to perform trivial algebraic manipulations like this one, but it can't - it's too dumb to do that.

Comment: @Mat - the optimizer may choose to do an index range scan as the access method. The values in the index are ordered already; if the clustering factor is high, the optimizer may decide that such a strategy is beneficial.

Comment: To clarify my comment further: in the **first**, trivial query, if you rewrite the condition as `length(code) - 5 > 0`, the FBI will not be used - for the same reason.

Comment: @mathguy  What is FBI. I am new!!!!

Comment: Sorry - FBI = Function Based Index.

Comment: @mathguy  Would you explain in depth

Comment: @mathguy Why FBI wont be used when length(code)  - 5 > 0

Comment: I already did. Try the FIRST query but write the condition as `length(code) - 5 > 0` and you will see that the index is not used. An index on a column (or a function-based index) can't be used if the column (or the function) does not appear on one side of the condition BY ITSELF, with no other operations, function calls, etc. around it, on the same side of the condition.

Comment: It seems I better make this into an actual Answer.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks

Comment: @mathguy I am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an `EMP` table with a column `HIREDATE`, and that column is indexed, then the optimizer may choose to use the index for accessing the table in a query with a condition like

```
... HIREDATE >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
```

to find employees hired in the last 12 months.

However, `HIREDATE` has to be **alone** on the left-hand side. If you add or subtract months or days to it, or if you wrap it within a function call like `ADD_MONTHS`, the index can't be used. The optimizer will not perform trivial arithmetic manipulations to convert the condition into one where `HIREDATE` by itself must satisfy an inequality.

The same happened in your second query. If you change the condition to

```
... length(i.code) > length(ii.code)
```

then the optimizer can use the function-based index on `length(code)`. But even in your first query, if you change the condition to

```
... length(code) - 5 > 0
```

the index will NOT be used, because this is not an inequality condition on `length(code)`. Again, the optimizer is not smart enough to perform trivial algebraic manipulations to rewrite this in a form where it's an inequality condition on `length(code)` itself.

Comment: If I have to use 'length(code) - 5', What is the solution for applying the index range scan?

Comment: I mean what is the solution to overcome to this restriction?

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin  - If you have to use `length(code) - 5` for some reason (and can't move the 5 to the other side), then the function-based index should not be on `length(code)`, but instead it should be on `length(code) - 5`.